# Get an array of JSON data from php database

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, json

I am kinda new to SQL and I am having a problem. I am following the tutorial from [Here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrieve-data-from-mysql-database-in-android-using-volley/) to try to get data from my database into my android app.

I have it working, but it only gets one line. I know it should be possible to iterate through the database and echo out every line that matches the ID to JSON, but I do not know how. How would I do this?

My current code:

```
<?php 

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

 $id  = $_GET['id'];

 require_once('dbConnect.php');

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM LATLON WHERE DeviceID='".$id."'";

 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

 $result = array();

 array_push($result,array(
 "INDEX"=>$res['INDEX'],
 "DeviceID"=>$res['DeviceID'],
 "LAT"=>$res['LAT'],
 "LON"=>$res['LON']
 )
 );

 echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

 mysqli_close($con);

 }
?>
```

---

**EDIT**
I edited my code to this, but I am getting nothing. Still not quite understanding what is happening. Thanks for all the help!

```
<?php 

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

 $id  = $_GET['id'];

 require_once('dbConnect.php');

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM LATLON WHERE DeviceID='".$id."'";

 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = $result->mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $array[] = $row;
}

 echo json_encode($array);

 mysqli_close($con);

 }
?>
```

Comment: Your code is wide open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Never trust user input, including `$id` in your example. Instead of building SQL queries by sticking strings together, read about [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). Alternatively, [with PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: OH! Thanks for the info. This is currently just a sample, but I definately need to clean the input!

Comment: Aren't you getting an error message? It should be `$result->fetch_array`, not `$result->mysqli_fetch_array`.

Comment: Don't edit the question to remove the problem. Solutions go in answers, not the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through `mysqli_fetch_array();`

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $array[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Still not quite sure what I am doing wrong. Am I implementing your code correctly?

Comment: Sorry, check the updated code. I used OO (object oriented) style and you were using procedural.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the OO interface, the method names don't begin with `mysqli_`, that's only used for procedural calls. You also have no variable named `$result`, the result is in `$r`.

So it should be:

```
while ($row = $r->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```

or:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```